# Excel documents are opening in Read only mode and cannot be edited with office 365 pro plus and IE11

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, share

I am running Windows server 2012 with SharePoint 2010 and the users with running windows 10 and Office 2013,

So recently i upgrade them all to office 365 Pro Plus

Since then, i can not edit in Excel through IE11

Yes i am getting Pop up message ( Read Only or Edit ) so whenever i choose edit the Excel open in Read Only Mode ..

Before the upgrade it was working fine..

So please can anyone give me a best solution ?

I have tried Many Methods Like

1- Click File > Options > Trust Center > Protect View, uncheck all Enable Protected View settings to disable Protect View temporarily, save the setting and restart Word to open this document.

2- HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\Identity\EnableADAL  --> D-WORD=0

I still have Office 15 in the register ( Is this have any related issue with office 16 )

Comment: One thing to check is whether this happens on another computer (or a phone with the Excel app installed).

Answer (score 1):

You might need to remove any browser plugins that are from a previous version of Office, then run an Office repair to install new browser plugins.

Office and IE do not enjoy mixed wave (14, 15, 16 etc.) software.

Your browser plugins might point to the wrong place (like a previous office install directory) to attempt to access Office software.

Comment: You mean mixed waves that there rest of Office 2013 still remaining ( so i thought maybe if i delete the folder 15 from regedit ) would it fix the problem, but am afraid it would effect other Apps .. What do you think ?? Plus i will try your method it sound making sense to me.

Comment: It's a combination of potential problems, however since you mention the issue occurs when trying to access files in the browser (IE), then the SharePoint browser plugin(s) may be the incorrect ones for your new office.

This is a very common issue.

I'm not even sure Office 2016 supports SharePoint 2010

Comment: Look I found inside the Add On this path : Name:     SharePoint OpenDocuments Class
Publisher:              Microsoft Corporation
Type:                   ActiveX Control
Architecture:           32-bit and 64-bit
Version:                16.0.9126.2227
File date:              ‎Tuesday, ‎November ‎6, ‎2018, ‏‎11:33 PM
Date last accessed:     ‎Today, ‎November ‎13, ‎2018, ‏‎1 minute ago
Use count:              53
Block count:            0
File:                   Interceptor.dll
Folder:                 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing to try is to just run a repair installation of Office. It's vanishingly unlikely to hurt, and if the problem is (for example) a missing plugin, this would fix it.